# What is the meaning of “these lederhosen are riding up my Bundesliga”?

Tags: dialogue, penguins-of-madagascar

What is common between German traditional trousers and German soccer/football league?

Scene where that sentence is said in the movie *Penguins of Madagascar*:

Comment: From the clip it seems the penguin doesn't say Lederhosen, but just Hosen.

Comment: This joke was extra funny to me because "bund" actually does mean "ass" in Urdu and Punjabi.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The *meaning* of the sentence is, "These lederhosen are riding up my butt." It's supposed to make kids watching the film giggle (and some adults, like me). The filmmakers didn't want to use the word "butt", so they chose a word that starts with "B" and sounds distinctly German ("Bundesliga") and is possibly familiar. They used that word instead. They expected the audience members' minds to replace the word when they heard it. Notice that the penguin who says the line is pulling his lederhosen out of his "Bundesliga" as he's saying it.

Comment: +1: Consider that this character also exclaims words like "SHIIT- _(pause)_ -aki mushrooms"

Comment: Out of context I assumed that this is a word play on FC Bayern Munich (Bayern being the German state most closely associated with Lederhosen and also the by far most successful club in the Bundesliga). Not sure if that's even intended, but it adds another funny layer to the exchange for me.

Comment: I would add here that this is also likely a slight on the penguin's grasp of German; he doesn't know the right word so he just uses football league name instead.

Answer (score 5):

There is no commonality at all, except these are words the audience may or may not be familiar with (less so Bundesliga and more so lederhosen) But more importantly, *sound* german...which is what they were obviously making fun of. German is often made fun of for how it sounds in English speaking media. [Tim Allen Gives a good example.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s9ehI6nyZNM)

Of course they're making fun of a very specific german stereotype, namely the Bavarians, with the lederhosen and lesser so the accordion.

But if you wanted to really pull something from nothing, [FC Bayern Munich](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=bc%20bayern&ia=news) is a top Bundesliga team.

This is an example of the [Gratuitous Foreign Language](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/GratuitousForeignLanguage) trope.

Comment: To elaborate on FC Bayern Munich (the most successful football club in Germany and also perhaps the one most hated by fans of other clubs): They are often pejoratively referred to as "Lederhosen". A common cheer heard at football matches against them is: "Zieht den Bayern die Lederhosen aus!" ("strip the lederhosen off the Bavarians"). Although [usually the opposite happens](https://www.bundesliga.com/en/bundesliga/clubs/fc-bayern-muenchen/stats).

Comment: @Philipp wait, so "These lederhosen are riding up my Bundasliga" could be a straight pun on the dominance of Bayern Munich riding up [the] Bundasliga [table]? Considering the popularity of German football around the world, I wouldn't say this is totally unlikely as a secondary in-joke for those in the know!

Comment: @Philipp This was my first association as well. Might be a second-layer in-joke.

Comment: @Philipp Seems it is other meaning of that sentence, it is logical.

Answer (score 4):

In English, the word "Bundesliga" sounds vaguely like "bunghole", which is a word often substituted by children for "butthole". So the joke is that the lederhosen are riding up his butt.

For example, "bunghole" was used extensively in *Beavis and Butthead*:

[image]

Comment: I'd go more with "buns". It has all those letters in that order. BUNdSliga.

Comment: `In English, the word "Bundesliga" sounds vaguely like "bunghole"` ... how on Earth have you arrived at that conclusion?

Comment: The same way the 5 people who upvoted me did. I'll clarify in the answer.